# getting Parser error for Asp.Net by IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I'm developing some Asp.Net website and I'm trying to run it on my IIS, I published the web (under build option) and put it under wwwroot, but I get this parser error below. shall I publish the web to add it in inetmgr? or just put the files in my project folder there? what's the point of publishing?

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

and this is the line which cause it.

```
Line 1:  <%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="App_Pages_Default, App_Web_av5ghx1x" %>
```

Comment: @James johnson - that is something that gets generated by VS when building and publishing the website.  I forget the conditions on which this gets modified, but I see it all the time.

Comment: @ePezhman - what's the error?  Have you configured the web app in IIS or are you just publishing to a subfolder of \inetpub\wwwroot?  If you're just publishing, then you're missing some steps - you need to set it up as an applicaiton in IIS, and probably other steps.

Comment: @DavidStratton: Huh... I've never noticed that. Is it something new to VS2010? Should it be there in the development environment?

Comment: It is not new to VS2010. This happens when you create a website instead of a web application in Visual Studio and allow the website to be updatable on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your publish settings. When you publish the website, uncheck

```
Allow this precompiled site to be updateable
```

That should take care of the extra the App_Web_av5ghx1x.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it's purpose is, but I would try removing `App_Web_av5ghx1x` from Inherits, and add the `CodeBehind` attribute:

```
<%@ page Language="C#" Autoeventwireup="true" CodeBehind="App_Pages_Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="App_Pages_Default" %>
```