# Running an ASP site with IIS app getting Parser Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I received an ASP site that someone made but I have never worked with ASP.  I watched a few tutorials and I am trying to run it locally with IIS.  But I get the following error:

[image: asp error]

The Global.asax file only contains that 1 line:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ImageReco.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

and in (what I think is the root dir) I only have the files
`ImageReco.csproj` & `ImageReco.csproj.user`
I don't have any file named `ImageReco.MvcApplication`

I tried changing the line in global.asax from:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ImageReco.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

to point to the file I have

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ImageReco.csproj" Language="C#" %>
```

I saw this post here that is old but seems to be the same problem:
[getting Parser error for Asp.Net by IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810102/getting-parser-error-for-asp-net-by-iis)
However since I didn't create or publish this site I don't really know how I would change the publish settings, or if I would have to download Visual Studio to do it, etc. I don'k code in C# so I don't really use VS.

Is this the problem though? Do I need to get VS and publish it? How would I do this?

Or is this something else???

I also saw this post:
["Parser Error Message: Could not load type" in Global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682216/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-in-global-asax)

But I don't know how to do a clean and rebuild? I already created mroe than 1 website in IIS, and also changed the global.asax file, which didn't help.

How would I do a clean and rebuild, what do I have to download?

Since I am new to VS here is my dir structure incase it helps, this is the folder I am trying to run it is called ImageReco, here are the cotnents

[image: Dir]

and it is withing this folder
[image]

I assume that is where I am supposed to run the app from no?

Thank You

Comment: Have you checked the bin directory? Also, ensure that IIS website is mapped to ImageReco directory path

Comment: The bin has some dll files no exe's. the IIS site is mapped to the ImageReco path

Comment: Open the project in Visual Studio, should give you more info on what the problem is, your going to  just have frustration modifying stuff outside of it.